# how to verify an xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

My function is going to load a local xml file and check **if it is well-formed**. If it's not well-formed  then pop up an alert.
This is my function to load xml file:

```
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET",xml_url,false); 
        xmlhttp.send(null);         
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

My program runs in Firefox. 
Is there any simple way to verify the xml file?
Thank you!

Comment: You want to verify what?

Comment: if the xml file is not well-formed, for example, <tag1>......</tagg1>.  I want to detect such errors and then pop up an alert

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to invoke FireFox's XML parser via its API (which I haven't used myself).  Looks like this may work:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Error_handling

But here is an older solution looks like using IE's MSXML (which is their XML parser):

```
 //We'll load the XML data into an MSXML DOM Document
 //We'll load in the XSD
 //We'll validate the data and report on the results

 var xmlData = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.5.0")
 xmlData.async = false

 //A SchemaCache is an object that can hold one or more schema references
 var xsd = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.5.0")

 //Each schema you wish to reference must be added to the cache
 //The first argument is for the Namespace URI
 xsd.add("", "order.xsd")

 //Tell the XMLDOMDocument where the schema(s) can be found
 xmlData.schemas = xsd

 //You don't want to load your "instance document"
 //until you've indicated that a schema should be used
 xmlData.validateOnParse = true //This is the default anyway
 xmlData.load("Order1.xml")

 if(xmlData.parseError.reason != "")
 {
     //There is either a "well-formed" or "validation" problem
     alert(xmlData.parseError.reason)
 }
 else
 {
     alert("Document is well-formed and valid!")
 }
```

Comment: Is this older solution is cross-browser compatible ? Does it work in Firefox and Chrome ? If not, can you please give me some helpful link to find the solution? I am just searching for a good solution which will validate a XML file in client side. :)